# Having problem in connecting to remote MongoDB Server

Tags: mongodb, windows-10, ubuntu-20.04, mongodb-compass

I tried to connect a remote MongoDB Server running on Ubuntu using MongoDB Compass on Windows. But I have problems connecting always as the IP of the Windows machine changes every day.

I did the following things to connect to the remote server-

1. Got the IP of the Client Machine, then allowed that IP on the firewall of the server machine on port 27017.

```
sudo ufw allow from client_machine_ip to any port 27017
```

Note: The ufw status looked okay.

2. Got the IP of the Server Machine, then on the MongoDB configuration file on the server, I modified the bindIp.

```
bindIp: 127.0.0.1,server_machine_ip
```

Note: I restarted mongod and it was okay too.

I was able to connect the remote MongoDB Server using MongoDB Compass successfully for the first time. Then I saw, the IP of the client machine was changing every day. So, every time, the client IP changes, I need to allow that IP on the firewall of the server machine (in which I am using the MongoDB Server) on port 27017. Could you help to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can update the firewall for port 27017 to allow from anywhere since client machine IP is not static.

```
sudo ufw allow 27017 #(this will allow from any IP)
```